# How can I export Realm database to a file in react native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I am building a react native app using Realm database. I want to export the realm database to a single file and then later import that file by another mobile device. How can I export and import Realm database in react native?

Answer (score 1):

This currently does not allow files to be exported via code within the `React-native`. The `Realm` module does not currently have that capability.

However, you can move the file yourself, copy it, and put it in the `Realm` library in `another project` to check it on `another device.` 
Or you can save the file and then use the `Realm studio` program to check the data.

**file path**

[image: file realm]

Comment: If I still want to accomplish this task, should I change to other databases such as sqlite? Will it solve the problem?

Comment: @NBDKhoa Not really. sqlite also has no function of taking and importing files.It also needs to be moved manually, and the sqlite tool can check the data.

Comment: @NBDKhoa If my answer was helpful, would you choose my answer?